# Can indexing optimize UPDATE statements?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-update, query-optimization

I am currently trying to optimize an UPDATE statement that performs once a day to update a column for over 10 million rows and it takes hours. It is very simple:

```
UPDATE table SET column = ''
```

This table has only 2-3 indexes which don't include the mentioned column.

Since the majority of the rows are already updated, can an index only for the mentioned column make sql server seek the column faster for a faster update? Thanks!

Comment: I guess, it would be better to provide the complete query,because UPDATE table SET column = '' is not for optimization. In any case without predicates you will get Table Scan

Comment: You're updating **every** row here; adding indexes on the column will more likely make the process slower, not faster.

Comment: Surely you don't need to update the column where it's already `''` so presumably you haven't shared the complete statement?

Comment: @Stu It's done on a daily basis to update new rows

Comment: Why not only update the rows you actually need to? i.e. add a where clause `WHERE Column <> '' OR Column IS NULL`? That should prevent a fair amount of unnecessary overhead

Comment: If you add an index *and* the `WHERE` clause, then you would see a significant improvement

Comment: *It's done on a daily basis to update new rows* - but that's not what you're doing, you're updating every row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that "the majority of the rows are already updated", you should probably add a `WHERE` condition, so as to only update the rows that really need to (as others have already said). Without a `WHERE` clause, **all** records will be updated, even those that already have the same value `''`.

So even if 90% of your records needed to be updated, it would still be a bit faster if you avoid the redundant updates. But in such cases having an index on that column can only slow the query, because every index has to be updated when the underlying table records are updated.

In order to benefit from an index, you need a query with *low selectivity*, just as with `SELECT`-queries. What can be considered "low enough" depends on many factors. Sometimes an index can help for 10-20% selectivity. Other times, contrary to popular belief, it can make things worse even for 1% selectivity.